# MongoDB - Is it possible to use $or with $cond?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I am trying to aggregate a field based on a date range. I can't figure out how to create a $cond expression that will evaluate more than one expression. I am trying to use the logical $or operator but with no luck.

```
db.project.aggregate(
    { $match : { brand : 4 } },
    { $project : {
        _id : 0,
        brand : 1,
        count : 1,
        day : 1}
    },  
     { $group : {
        _id : "$brand",
        TotalCount : { $sum : "$count" },        
        TimeRangeCount : {$sum: { $cond: [ { $gte: [ "$day", new Date(2014, 0, 6) ], {$or: [$lte: [ "$day", new Date(2014, 0, 8) ]]} }, "$count", 0 ] }}

    }}    
    )
```

Is it possible to nest $or within $cond?

Thanks!

Comment: so did it worked?

Answer (score 8):

I believe I got it using $and

```
db.project.aggregate(
    { $match : { brand : 4 } },
    { 
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            brand : 1,
            count : 1,
            day : 1
        }
    },  
    { 
        $group : {
            _id : "$brand",
            TotalCount : { $sum : "$count" },        
            TimeRangeCount : {
                $sum: { 
                    $cond: [
                        {$and: [
                            {$gte: ["dDay", new Date(2014, 0, 6)]},
                            {$lte: ["$day", new Date(2014, 0, 8)]}
                        ]}, 
                        "$count", 
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }    
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, yes you can use $or within a $cond.

However, in your case this would be semantically incorrect as you are looking for a range **between** dates.

For future reference you could use something like this, if for example you wanted to map multiple values to a single value. This is basically saying "if you encounter *val1* or *val2* or *val3* in *someField* change them to *val4*.

```
db.someCollection.aggregate([
{
    someField: {
        $cond: [
            {$or: [
            {$eq: ['$someField', 'val1']},
            {$eq: ['$someField', 'val2']},
            {$eq: ['$someField', 'val3']}
        ]
    },
    'val4',
    '$someField'
  ]}
}]
```